# How to get an ARDUINO to read an open collector RAM ic?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to set a very simple arduino program to test just ONE address of a AM27ls01 or SN74S301.

As the data output is an open collector I have connected it to a 5v supply by a 300ohms resistor hoping for when data out put is low it gets shorted to ground and I get a LOW signal. Or when data is HIGH the collector is open and I get a HIGH signal. But no matter what data I store or read I am always getting a HIGH data output.

I am also trying to follow the write and read sequence provided by the datasheet.

So I am not sure where my code is wrong.

[image] 
[image]

CODE

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define CE1         14  // A0
#define CE2         15  // A1
#define CE3         16  // A2
#define WE          17  // A3

//ROWS
#define XA0          2  // D2
#define XA1          3  // D3
#define XA2          4  // D4
#define XA3          5  // D5
//COLS
#define XA4          6  // D6
#define XA5          7  // D7
#define XA6          8  // D8
#define XA7          9  // D9
// numbers of words 4x4x4x4=256


#define DI          11  // D11
#define DO          18  // A4

int ret = 0;

void setBus(){
  digitalWrite(XA0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(XA1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(XA3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(XA4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA5, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(XA6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA7, LOW);
}

void clearBus(){
  digitalWrite(XA0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA4, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(XA7, LOW);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
//WRITE//////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////

void write(int d){

  //WRITE
  Serial.println("******Writing start******");

  // BIT TO WRITE /////////////////////
  if (d == 1) {
    digitalWrite(DI, HIGH);
    Serial.println("Write = 1");
  }else{
    digitalWrite(DI, LOW);
    Serial.println("Write = 0");
  }

  // ADDRESS
  Serial.println("Set write address");
  setBus();
  digitalWrite(CE1, LOW);

  //WRITE
  digitalWrite(WE, LOW);

  //RELEASE
  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  Serial.println("Storing bit");
  digitalWrite(CE1, HIGH);
  clearBus();

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
//READ//////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////

void read(){

  clearBus();
  //ROW
  Serial.println("*****Reading start******");
  Serial.println("Set read address");
  setBus();
  digitalWrite(CE1, LOW);

  //READ DATA
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A4);
  float voltage= sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  Serial.print("Read voltage = ");
  Serial.println(voltage);
  Serial.print("Read data = ");
  ret = digitalRead(DO);
  Serial.println(ret);

  //RELEASE
  digitalWrite(CE1, HIGH);
  clearBus();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
//SETUP//////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("START");

  pinMode(XA0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(XA7, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(DI, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DO, INPUT);
  pinMode(CE1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CE2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CE3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(WE, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(WE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CE1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CE2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CE3, HIGH);

  clearBus();

  write(1);
  read();
  write(0);
  read();

}

void loop() {

}
```

SERIAL OUT

```
START
******Writing start******
Write = 1
Set write address
Storing bit
*****Reading start******
Set read address
Read voltage = 0.13
Read data = 0
******Writing start******
Write = 0
Set write address
Storing bit
*****Reading start******
Set read address
Read voltage = 4.99
Read data = 1
```

Comment: That pullup is pretty strong... I would have started with 3K instead of 300. Second, regarding chip-selects, the data sheet says (in effect) "when any one is high, the output is off". The code seems to drive only /S1 called `CE1`. Maybe tie the other two to ground, and only drive /S1 like you already are. Finally, make little routines that do nice things for you to make it easier to see what goes on: setAddress(), strobeRead() --- whatever makes sense.  Have fun!

Comment: thanks mike, i think it is working now. I just have one last question. When I store 1 I am reading 0. I believe that is the nature of the open collector. As the output transistor is forward biased it's collector gets grounded then what you read is an inverted bit to what has been stored. is that correct?

Comment: Yep. The datasheet says the value on `/O` is the *complement of data entered*, which is indicated by the bar over the `O`. This  means we save a zero and get a one, and visa versa. You are correct that an open collector output acts as an inverter; they could have added an internal inverter to get "true" data out, but didn't... maybe because of propagation delays and timing??? Don't know.  Glad to hear it's working better!